# Simple array object from nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript

It's pretty simple. I have this :

```
[{"key":"jim","values":{"count":2,"total":79}},
 {"key":"carl","values":{"count":1,"total":120}},
 {"key":"stacy","values":{"count":3,"total":90}}]
```

and I would like this :

```
[{ "key": 'jim', count: 2, total: 79 },
  { "key": 'carl', count: 1, total: 120},
  { "key": 'stacy', count:3, total: 90}];
```

I've read stuff about nested object, and other kind of data manipulation with Javascript but I can't solve my issue. I guess I need to use `.map` method but I can't make it work. thanks.

Comment: just use a normal loop. don't mess with .map until you've got basic looping down.

Comment: I'am a beginner what's a normal loop ?

Comment: And how, exactly, are we to magically map `jim` to `Louise` or similar?! If you're a beginner, begin with beginner's tutorials and work up. SO isn't the right place for seeking tutorials.

Comment: I've been following this tutorials http://learnjsdata.com I can do almost everything. It's just that I'm used to work with d3 and where there is no d3 option I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one buddy ! As you said you are beginner I did a basic looping with step by step implementation please go through the code. 
This code will work for dynamic one level nested object.

```
var arr = [{"key":"jim","values":{"count":2,"total":79}},
     {"key":"carl","values":{"count":1,"total":120}},
     {"key":"stacy","values":{"count":3,"total":90}}]

var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)  {
   var currentObj = arr[i];
   var Obj = {};  // Temporary object
   for (var key in currentObj) {
      if (typeof currentObj[key] === 'object') {  // If it is nested object
        for (var deepkey in currentObj[key]) {    // Loop again
          Obj[deepkey] = currentObj[key][deepkey];
        }
      }
    else {
      Obj[key] = currentObj[key];  
    }
  }
  newArr.push(Obj);
 }

console.log(newArr); // [{ "key": 'jim', count: 2, total: 79 },
                         { "key": 'carl', count: 1, total: 120},
                         { "key": 'stacy', count:3, total: 90}];
```

Will work for different inputs

```
var arr = [{"key":"jim", "hey": {"ting": "bing"} ,"values": {"count":2,"total":79}},
 {"key":"carl","values":{"count":1,"total":120}},
  {"key":"stacy","values":{"count":3,"total":90}}]
```

Dynamic one level nested objects

Demo link : https://jsbin.com/nojafo/6/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop to make a new array with format you want.

```
var initial = [{"key":"jim","values":{"count":2,"total":79}},
{"key":"carl","values":{"count":1,"total":120}},
{"key":"stacy","values":{"count":3,"total":90}}];

var target =  [];
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i< initial.length; i++) {
   obj = {"key": initial[i].key, count: initial[i].values.count, total: initial[i].values.total};
   target.push(obj);
  }

console.log(target);
```

Comment: Good one buddy ! But this solution won't work if nested object is having more than 2 items / dynamic nested items

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I finally find something that's simpler to me :

```
var input = [{"key":"jim","values":{"count":2,"total":79}},
 {"key":"carl","values":{"count":1,"total":120}},
 {"key":"stacy","values":{"count":3,"total":90}}];

 var output = input.map(function(item) {
     return {
      key: item.key,
    count: item.values.count,
    total: item.values.total
  }
 });

 console.log(output);
```

Comment: Nice one dude ! But It won't work for dynamic objects (like if key names are not count, total)

Comment: Yes ok I understand. Since I'm working on react app and calling some web app, most of time my key names are well defined. But I understand now why ur answers is so complex :) good to know.

Comment: Yes cool dude !! Loved you explaination. Great keep it up. I think now you can vote me up and mark it as answer :) kidding